# Python script runs via apache when permissions are 755 but gives Error 500 when 777?

Tags: cgi, chmod, 777

I uploaded a basic python script to my shared hosting at Dreamhost, and changed the permissions to `777`. It ran fine from the shell (via SSH) but would display a 'Server Error' when called from the browser.

In the error.log, the error was `'Premature end of script headers'`.

I wrote to DreamHost, who (surprisingly quickly) replied by changing the permissions to `755`, and the script started working properly in apache (I could see the output in the browser).

But this doesn't seem right - how can adding extra lenient permissions break anything from functioning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allowing anyone to edit a CGI script means that it would be easy to insert a backdoor into the system. httpd is correctly disallowing a suspect program to be run.